# Relay mutation expects data fetched by Relay

Tags: relayjs

I have two Relay mutations that I'm nesting to first add an object then set its name. I believe what I'm passing to the second mutation is in fact data fetched by Relay, but it appears to disagree with me. The code in the React view is as follows:

```
Relay.Store.update(
        new AddCampaignFeatureLabelMutation({
            campaign: this.props.campaign
        }),
        {
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                Relay.Store.update(
                    new FeatureLabelNameMutation({
                        featureLabel: data.addCampaignFeatureLabel.featureLabelEdge.node,
                        name: this.addLabelInputField.value
                    })
                );
            },
            onFailure: () => {}
        }
    );
```

This does work, but gives me a warning:

```
Warning: RelayMutation: Expected prop `featureLabel` supplied to `FeatureLabelNameMutation` to be data fetched by Relay. This is likely an error unless you are purposely passing in mock data that conforms to the shape of this mutation's fragment.
```

Why does Relay think the data isn't fetched? Do I maybe need to explicitly return the new featureLabel in the payload somehow?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and it took me some time to figure out what was going on, so this might help others:

As the warning says, you have to provide an entity to the mutation that was fetched by Relay. BUT what the warning does not say is that it has to be fetched with the mutation in mind.

So basically you have to add the mutation you are going to execute on it in the future in the initial query like this:

```
          fragment on Person {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            language,
            ${UpdatePersonMutation.getFragment('person')}
          }
```

This will add the necessary pieces to the entity in the store which are needed by the mutation.

In you case what you have to do is to add the `FeatureLabelNameMutation` `getFragment` to your `AddCampaignFeatureLabelMutation` query. This will bring back your `featureLabel` entity with the necessary information for the `FeatureLabelNameMutation` to succeed without warning.

The Relay documentation is very very poor on this and many other areas.

Comment: Bit late of a reply here, but that is what I ended up finding out as well. Agreed on the documentation being spotty; I ended up just going to the source to figure this one out.

Comment: @Christine, I have a very similar issue. Mind taking a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35197523/2030321)? I'd be eternally thankful!

Comment: damn, I always forget including the fragments, and keep scratching my head... shouldn't have learnt this by now by the sheer number of times I've made this mistake. Not that the error message helps much....

Comment: Thank you!  Spent hours on this.

Comment: I'd like to add something here: the reason that we need to add the `getFragment('person')` portion is it will create an object with the hidden attribute `__fragments__` which is used by Relay to track its objects. So if you just passing an object without `__fragments__` to the mutation it will still not work, even you passed all correct values in that object. And Relay will still give that ambiguous warning.

Answer (score 7):

Relay expects any fragments for your mutation to come from your `props`. Since you're using `data` coming from your callback and not something from your container props Relay raises that warning.

Take a look at the source: https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/mutation/RelayMutation.js#L289-L307

Comment: So, this is just a warning and not going to cause any issue in using the data?

Comment: @javvvva No, see the answer below. The warning actually highlights a real wrong doing, but doesn't explain it very well.