# Not getting payload after React-relay nested mutation

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

This is a follow-up question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776023/2030321) posted earlier on SO about a react-relay mutation warning.

> "In you case what you have to do is to add the FeatureLabelNameMutation getFragment to your AddCampaignFeatureLabelMutation query."

As with the OP in that question, I too want to make a nested relay mutation and I've tried doing what @Christine is suggesting, but I'm uncertain on where exactly to put the `getFragment` part.

In my application, I want to create a "task" with multiple nested "sub-tasks" when the user creates a task.

What I have tried works, but I don't get the returned PayLoad for the `AddSubTaskMutation` mutation. Here's what I've tried so far:

#### AddTaskMutation.js

```
export default class AddTaskMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    classroom: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Classroom { 
        id,
        tasks(last: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
                id,
                ${AddSubTaskMutation.getFragment('task')}, //<-- what I tried adding 
            },
          }
        },
      }`,
    }`,
  };
  ...
```

#### AddSubTaskMutation.js

```
export default class AddSubTaskMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    task: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Task { 
        id,
      }`,
   };
   ...
```

#### TaskCreate.js

```
Relay.Store.update(
  new AddTaskMutation({
    title,
    instruction,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    published: isPublished,
    classroom: this.props.classroom
  }),
  {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      let {taskEdge} = response.addTask;
      for (let subTask of this.state.subTaskContent) {
        Relay.Store.update(
          new AddSubTaskMutation({
            task: taskEdge.node,
            type: subTask['type'],
            position: subTask['position'],
            ...
          }),
        );
      }
    }
  }
)
...
export default Relay.createContainer(TaskCreate, {
  prepareVariables() {
    return {
      limit: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || 9007199254740991,
    };
  },
  fragments: {
    classroom: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Classroom {
        id,
        tasks(last: $limit) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              ...
            }   
          }
        },
        ...
        ${AddTaskMutation.getFragment('classroom')},
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Apart from not getting the payload, I'm also getting the following warnings:

```
Warning: RelayMutation: Expected prop `task` supplied to `AddSubTaskMutation` to be data fetched by Relay. This is likely an error unless you are purposely passing in mock data that conforms to the shape of this mutation's fragment.
Warning: writeRelayUpdatePayload(): Expected response payload to include the newly created edge `subTaskEdge` and its `node` field. Did you forget to update the `RANGE_ADD` mutation config?
```

So my question is: where do i add the `getFragment` in `AddTaskMutation.js` to make this work?

Comment: Using `getFragment` for a mutation is somewhat uncommon - it's only needed when the mutation itself needs additional data *before* the mutation executes.

It's a bit weird, then, to see your mutation requesting up to 1000 other tasks, when you really just want to add a new one. Are you using any of that data for the mutation itself?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the issue is that you don't really understand what the mutation "fragment" is for vs. the rest of the mutation properties (fat query & configs). The warning you are seeing is related to Relay noticing that the task prop you are giving it isn't from the `AddSubtaskMutation` fragment, it's from the `AddTaskMutation` mutation query. But that's really just a red herring; your issue is that you don't need those fragments at all, you just need to configure the mutation appropriately to create your new nodes & edges. Here's a couple suggestions.

Step #1

- Get rid of the fragments in both `AddTaskMutation` and `AddSubtaskMutation`, they seem unnecessary
- Modify `AddTaskMutation`'s constructor to take a bunch of fields for the task and a `classroomID` to specify the affected classroom
- Similarly, modify `AddSubTaskMutation` to take a bunch of fields for the subtask and a `taskID` to specify the parent task
- Make sure your `AddTaskMutation` payload includes the modified classroom and the new task edge
- Define a `RANGE_ADD` mutation using the `classroomID` to target the classroom for the new task
- Define a `FIELDS_CHANGE` mutation on `AddSubtaskMutation` that mutates the parent using the given `taskID` (I'm not sure how you're storing subtasks, probably a connection). You can change this to a `RANGE_ADD` if you really want.

Step #2: Simplify

- It seems unnecessary to do this in 1+N mutations (N subtasks), when you seem to have all the information at the start. I'd modify the input of `AddTaskMutation` to accept a new task and an array of subtasks, and do it all at once...

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll test these suggestions at work tomorrow morning and will come back to you. Many thanks again!